# Request duration? Via Paw HTTP Client

Tags: paw-app

Request duration? Via Paw HTTP Client:  Is there a way to see how long a request took?   I can't seem to find out how how something took.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the request duration in the status bar right after sending the request:

[image: See HTTP Request Duration in Paw]

Though, Paw is optimized for debug and testing, and is always slower than an actual HTTP client. Durations are always significantly higher than other clients.

Comment: Note that we're working at optimizing the request time, the long term goal is to have a fast client with all the existing debug features.

Comment: Nice thanks. If it can compete with JMeter for load testing that'd be amazing too.

Comment: That's what I want to have, but definitively not the core goal of Paw.